# Multi-level C++ pointer returns wrong value

Tags: c++, pointers, multi-level

As the title states, my multi-level pointer returns the wrong value when I try to de-reference it **with offsets**. I want to get 029DAAE8 but it returns 3259e1029d2010

Pointer info:

029DAAE8 = 36

029DAAE8 + 0 = 029DAAE8

029D2000 + 10 = 029DAAE8

029DA9C0 + 384 = 029D2000

ac_client.exe + 10F4F4 = 029DA9C0

I'm currently using the follow code:

```
uintptr_t ResolveMLPointer(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets){
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i) {
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)ptr, &ptr, sizeof(ptr), 0);
    ptr += offsets[i];
}
return ptr;
}
```

and to call it I'm using:

```
uintptr_t ammoAddr = ResolveMLPointer(hProcess, dynamicPtrBaseAddr, { 0x384, 0x10, 0x0 });
```

[image containing pointer config in CE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJEHD.png)

Comment: Are not offsets in PE 4 byte values, but you read 8 bytes (sizeof(ptr))?

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!! I spent like 8 hours debugging this.